# How to find a Matrix given the kernel and image of the associated transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to find the Matrix of a lineal transformation f: R^3 -> R^2

I know Ker (f) = [(1, −1, 3),(2, 2, 0)] and  Im (f) = [(5, 1)]

I only have to find one transformation that fits this. If there are more it doesn't matter.

Thanks !

I can start with this :

F (1,-1,3) = (0,0) ; F(2,2,0) = (0,0) ;  F(0,1,0) = (5,1)

but i have no idea how to find the matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\text{im}\; f = [(5,1)]$ is a one dimensional subspace, we know $f(e_i)$ is a scalar multiple of $(5,1)$ for each basis (I'll assume these are column vectors.). Hence, we can define the matrix of $f$ up to a scalar multiple to be $$[f]_{e_i} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 5x &
5y\\ 1 & x & y\end{bmatrix}.$$
Applying this matrix to your kernel vectors yields a system of equations in two variables.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.