# Transformation matrix from kernel and image

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to find transformation matrix from given kernel and image in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

$$
f: (\mathbb{Z}_7)^3 \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_7)^2
$$

Ker(f) = [(1, −1, 3), (2, 2, 0)]

Im(f) = [(5, 1)]

This question is similiar to [this from pedro aisenson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4102825/how-to-find-a-matrix-given-the-kernel-and-image-of-the-associated-transformation), however, I would like to find all the solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_7$.

I have done

$$\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 5x & 5y \\
1 & 1x & y
\end{pmatrix}*
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
-1 & 2 \\
3 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$x = -1, y = \frac{-2}{3}$

Now I get transformation matrix for one solution in $\mathbb{R}$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
5 & -5 & \frac{-10}{3} \\
1 & -1 & \frac{-2}{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I get all solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_7$?

Comment: Thank you, yes, you are right, I forgot to write it there.

Comment: So where is the difficulty in understanding that $3\times(-2)=-6=1$  in $\mathbb Z_7$? $3f=-2d\implies f=(-2)\times(-2)d=4d$

Comment: I've missed that 3 x (-2) = 1, but now i understand that. Thank you

Comment: So, you should have done $x = -1, y =(-2)\times 3^{-1}$ Right ? We are in $\Bbb Z_7$ not in $\Bbb R$

Comment: I'm talking about the $\frac xy$ notation, which bothers me. I don't know if it's allowed but it shocks me: it looks like you're in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, I got it, y = 4, because $4 \equiv \frac{-2}{3} mod(7)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your ker and im, $f$ is a map from ${\Bbb Z_7}^3$ to ${\Bbb Z_7}^2$ so its matrix is of the form
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{pmatrix},\quad a,b,c,d,e\in\Bbb Z_7.$$
The condition on ker gives:
$$a-b+3c=d-e+3f=2a+2b=2d+2e=0,$$
i.e.
$$e=-d,\quad b=-a,\quad 2d+3f=0,\quad 2a+3c=0.$$
Multiplying the equation $2d+3f=0$ by $-2$ (the inverse of $3$ modulo $7$), we can replace it by $-4d+f=0.$ Similarly, $2a+3c=0$ is equivalent to $-4a+c=0,$
hence
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&-a&4a\\d&-d&4d\end{pmatrix}.$$
The condition on im then becomes $a=5d$ and the conclusion is that "all the solutions" are
$$A=d\begin{pmatrix}5&-5&-1\\1&-1&4\end{pmatrix},\quad d\in\Bbb Z_7,\quad d\ne0,$$
where (thanks to Stéphane) the $20$ in the upper right corner has been replaced by $-1\pmod7.$

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain how you got f = 4d and c = 4a?

Comment: Okay, I understand that now. Thank you